# how can the exitXXX function knows what rule has been match

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have an exitXXX function in my listener, how can it knows what rules has been matched. In exitEffectiveAddress16(), how can i know it matched "BX '+' DI" or "BP '+' SI" ?

```
effectiveAddress16  :   'byte [' (BX '+' SI 
            |   BX '+' DI
            |   BP '+' SI
            |   BP '+' DI
            |   SI
            ;
```

Thanks Peter

Answer (score 1):

You need to **label your rule alternatives** to gain that specificity.  The ANTLR grammar language provides the alternative label, which looks like a python comment as shown below:

```
effectiveAddress16  :   'byte [' (BX '+' SI     # effAddBXSI
            |   BX '+' DI                       # effAddBXDI
            |   BP '+' SI                       # effAddBPSI
            |   BP '+' DI                       # effAddBPDI
            |   SI                              # effAddSI
            ;
```

When you do this and regenerate your visitor and/or listener, you will find methods to override for each of these specific alternatives for the rule.  So instead of generating one handler for `effectiveAddress16`, you'll get one handler for each of the labeled alternatives.  Then you know for sure which one matched.

Answer (score 1):

In your `exitEffectiveAddress16` function you get an `EffectiveAddress16Context` as parameter. This contains contains member functions for each of the referenced rules and tokens in that rule. You can check them if they return `!= null` to see if that rule/token has been matched. In cases, where the same rule/token can be matched multiple times **in a single top level alt** the rule/token access function actually returns an array and you need an additional condition to determine which of the occurences matched. The `BX` in your case appears only once in each alt, so there's just a single return value in the `BX()` access function (same for `SI` and `DI`).

For more info see [Rule Context Objects](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#rule-context-objects) in the ANTLR4 documentation.

Comment: thank you everyone. I finally resolved it by adding: returns [xxx] to the grammar.